# Induction for Vandermonde Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Given real numbers $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$, define the  Vandermonde
>   matrix by $V=(V_{ij}) = (x^j_i)$.  That is,  $$V =
> \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}   1 & x_1    & x^2_1     & \cdots &
>  x^{n-1}_1     & x^n_1  \\
>                                      1 & x_2    & x^2_2     & \cdots & x^{n-1}_2     & x^n_2  \\
>                                 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots    &        & \vdots        & \vdots \\
>                                      1 & x_{n-1}& x^2_{n-1} & \cdots & x^{n-1}_{n-1} & x^n_{n-1}  \\
>                                      1 & x_n    & x^2_n     & \cdots & x^{n-1}_n     & x^n_n   
>              \end{array}\right).$$ Prove that $\det(V) = \prod_{1\le i<j\le n} (x_j-x_i)$ by the following inductive steps.  Recall first
>   that adding a multiple of one row to another will not change the
>   determinant of a matrix.  This is also true if you add a multiple of
>   one column to another.  Finally remember that the determinant is
>   linear in each row when you leave the other ones fixed.
>
> a. Subtract $x_1$ times each column from the column to its right,
>   starting with the last column. That is, subtract $x_1$ times the
>   $(n-1)$-st column from the $n$-th column, $x_1$ times the $(n-2)$-nd
>   column from the $(n-1)$-st column, etc.
>
> b.  Then subtract the first row from all of the other rows.
>
> c.  Finally observe that each row has a common factor that can be
>   pulled out of the determinant.
>
> d. After these three steps are done, expand the resulting determinant
>   in cofactors across the first row.
>
> e.  You should see at this point how to apply the induction step.

What I have so far: I have been told that for the induction step I have to first first show that it is true for an $(n-1)$$\times$$(n-1)$ matrix and then show that it is true for an $n$$\times$$n$ matrix (I believe?). I kind of think that my resulting matrix after the steps is incorrect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the last row multiplied by -1 to all other rows, and we get,

det$|V|$=det$\left|\begin{array}{}
   0 & x_1-x_n & x_1^2-x_n^2 & \cdots & x_1^n-x_n^n \\
   0 & x_2-x_n & x_2^2-x_n^2 & \cdots & x_2^n-x_n^n \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
   0 & x_{n-1}-x_n & x_{n-1}^2-x_n^2 & \cdots & x_{n-1}^n-x_n^n \\
   1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n \\
  \end{array}  \right|
$

=det$\left|\begin{array}{}
    x_1-x_n & x_1^2-x_n^2 & \cdots & x_1^n-x_n^n \\
    x_2-x_n & x_2^2-x_n^2 & \cdots & x_2^n-x_n^n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    x_{n-1}-x_n & x_{n-1}^2-x_n^2 & \cdots & x_{n-1}^n-x_n^n \\
  \end{array}  \right|
$

=$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_k-x_n)$ det$\left|\begin{array}{}
    1 & x_1+x_n & x_1^2+x_1x_n+x_n^2 & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x_1^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
    1 & x_2+x_n & x_2^2+x_2x_n+x_n^2 & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x_2^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    1 & x_{n-1}+x_n & x_{n-1}^2+x_{n-1}x_n+x_n^2 & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{n-1}^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
  \end{array}  \right|
$

=$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_k-x_n)$ det$|V_1|$

In $V_1$, first add 1st column multiplied by $-x_n$ to 2nd column, and add 1st column multiplied by $-x_n^2$ to 3nd column, ..., and add 1st column multiplied by $-x_n^{n-1}$ to $(n-1)$'s column, we get

det$|V_1|$ = det$\left|\begin{array}{}
    1 & x_1 & x_1^2+x_1x_n & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-2}x_1^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
    1 & x_2 & x_2^2+x_2x_n & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-2}x_2^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2+x_{n-1}x_n & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-2}x_{n-1}^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
  \end{array}  \right|
$

Then add 2nd column multiplied by $-x_n$ to 3rd column, ..., and add 2nd column multiplied by $-x_n^{n-2}$ to $(n-1)$'s column, we get

det$|V_1|$ = det$\left|\begin{array}{}
    1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-3}x_1^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
    1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-3}x_2^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & \cdots & \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-3}x_{n-1}^{n-k-1}x_n^{k} \\
  \end{array}  \right|
$

Repeat above process, and use induction hypothesis, we have

det$|V_1|$ = det$\left|\begin{array}{}
    1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-1} \\
    1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & \cdots & x_{n-1}^{n-1} \\
  \end{array}  \right|
$ = $\prod_{1\le i<j\le n-1} (x_j-x_i)$

So finally

det$|V|$ =$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_k-x_n)$ det$|V_1|$ = $\prod_{1\le i<j\le n} (x_j-x_i)$

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this. And I marked it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

File 1 - file i, i from 2 to n. Then use Laplace (cofactors, i dont know how it is said in english). Then use the principle of inclusión-exclusión.