# For which values of $a,b,c$ is the matrix $A$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{pmatrix}$
$$\Rightarrow\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}b&c\\b^2&c^2\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}a&c\\a^2&c^2\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\a^2&b^2\end{vmatrix}\\=ab^2-a^2b-ac^2+a^2c+bc^2-b^2c\\=a^2(c-b)+b^2(a-c)+c^2(b-a).$$

---

Clearly, $$\left\{\det(A)\neq0\left|\begin{matrix}c\neq b\\a\neq c\\b\neq a\\a,b,c\neq 0\end{matrix}\right.\right\}\\$$

Is it sufficient to say that the matrix is invertible provided that all 4 constraints are met? Would Cramer's rule yield more explicit results for $a,b,c$ such that $\det(A)\neq0$?

Comment: The matrix is invertible if one of $a,b,c$ are zero, but the other two aren't zero and aren't equal (thanks copper.hat for this correction). So the condition that $a,b,c \neq 0$ is not necessary. However, your other 3 conditions are necessary. See the answers below for details.

Comment: Look up Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: It is invertible **iff** the $a,b,c$ are distinct.

Comment: By $a,b,c\neq 0$ you must mean all of them simultaneously equal to zero?

Comment: I found that the determinant is instead $-(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$. This means that as long as you satisfy your first 3 constraints ($a\neq c, a \neq b, b \neq c$, then you don't need to stipulate the fourth with $a,b,c \neq 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix is the special case of so-called Vandermonde Matrix (See [Induction for Vandermonde Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238455/induction-for-vandermonde-matrix)).

det($A$)$=(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$. So if $a\neq b,a\neq c, b\neq c, \space$ det$(A)\neq 0$.

Comment: My text defines $$V=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\a_0&a_1&\cdots&a_n\\a_0^2&a_1^2&\cdots&a_n^2\\\cdot&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a_0^n&a_1^n&\cdots&a_n^n\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is the equivalent of $V^T$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238455/induction-for-vandermonde-matrix). How does the algorithm differ with a first column of 1's vs. a first row of 1's?

Comment: Transpose matrice have same determinant. So there are no difference in algorithm. Or you can simply change operations on columns to rows, which will get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

suppose the matrix is singular. then so is its transpose, which must annihilate some non-zero vector $(h,g,f)$

this gives three equations:
$$
fa^2 + ga+ h =0 \\
fb^2 + gb+ h =0 \\
fc^2 + gc+ h =0 \\
$$
we know from the algebra of fields that a quadratic equation can have at most two roots, so the three values $a,b,c$ cannot all be different

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a square matrix, $\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{pmatrix}$

If $B$ is obtained from $A$ by adding a multiple of a row of $A$ to another row in $A$, $\det(B)=\det(A)\Rightarrow\text{let }B=\begin{pmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{pmatrix}\\\Rightarrow\det(B)=\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}b-a&b^2-a^2\\c-a&c^2-a^2\end{vmatrix}=(c^2-a^2)(b-a)-(b^2-a^2)(c-a)\\\\=(c-a)(b-a)((c-a)-(b-a))=(c-a)(b-a)(c-b)\\\therefore\det(A)\neq0\iff\begin{cases}a\neq c\\a\neq b\\b\neq c\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

This is a transpose of the Vandermonde matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

According to the wikipedia page, the determinant of the matrix will be non-zero precisely when none of the elements $a, b$, or $c$ are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the determinant as $(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$, so $\det(A)$ is nonzero precisely when $a,b,c$ are all distinct (note that one of $a,b,c$ can be zero).

Your matrix is the $3\times 3$ case of the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), whose determinant is generally a similar product of differences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is enough. Basically, if you are trying to solve:

$$\begin{pmatrix}d_1&d_2&d_3\end{pmatrix}A = \begin{pmatrix}y_1&y_2&y_3\end{pmatrix}$$ you are looking for a polynomial $f(x)=d_1+d_2x+d_3x^2$ such that $f(a)=y_1$, $f(d_2)=y_2$, and $f(d_3)=y_3$.

This we can find by simple interpolation of polynomials - given any $n$ distinct $a_i$ and $n$ distinct $b_i$ we can find a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree at most $n$ such that $p(a_i)=b_i$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\det(A)= \det\begin{pmatrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{pmatrix}= \det\begin{pmatrix}1&a&a^2\\0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{pmatrix} \\
=\det\begin{pmatrix}b-a&(b-a)(b+a)\\c-a&(c-a)(c+a)\end{pmatrix} =(b-a)(c-a)\det\begin{pmatrix}1&b+a\\1&c+a\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You need one more step to reach $\det(A) =(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)$ and another to say this must be non-zero and so $a,b,c$ must be distinct

Comment: @Henry Yes I need 2 more steps to provide ALL details to the solver, and don't leave anything for him to do....I think from here the rest is straightforward...

Comment: isn't this $\det(A^T)$?. I know that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$. Did you rearrange this before taking $\det$ because $A^T$ is a Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: @BenjaminLoya Yes, I used $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$. I rearranged because the first row contained all ones, after transposing the first column  contains all ones, which makes row reduction easy. Vandermonde matrices have this property, but it is this property which makes the computation easy, not the Vandermonde property.